# httpd proxy any domain

Tags: apache, proxy

Is it possible to configure a vhost on httpd that accepts any domain received and proxies to the actual website? Like subdomain wildcard but for the domain.

I'm assuming that tools like Squid Proxy can do this just fine, I'm just curious if it can be done with apache.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that is possible, but you don't even need a proxy for that. The apache http server offers the concept of a "default virtual host". Which is exactly what you want: that host is responsible to respond to incoming requests to http hosts that do *not* have a specific configuration.

The default typically simply is the first of all hosts defined inside an apache http server.

---

An alternative I personally use is to setup the virtual hosts by just a basic configuration (name, admin and the like), but to include the actual content configuration (DocumentRoot and rewriting stuff) from a separate file). That way you can easily share the same setup between many virtual hosts but still have individual configuration options per domain, subdomain, http host, however you want to call that (there is no difference for the http server anyway, it is all http hosts).